# Enlarge joint anchor icon in Unity editor

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, icons, editor

When a joint (hinge joint or configurable joint) is used in Unity the anchor is represented by a brown arrow icon in the Unity Scene window.

It is way too small. I want to enlarge it to see it easier. Is this possible, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For positioning purposes, I've found a solution: Clicking on "Edit Joint Angular Limits" (Unity 2017.3+ I guess) displays a circle that represents the angular limit. This circle is centered on the anchor, naturally. So it helps locating and positioning the anchor.